# Can InnoDB be used only in memory?

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a local server for running tests, part of this is the database is dropped very regularly (before almost every scenario). The database itself only contains the rows required to carry out the test.

Is there a way to use InnoDB so that it never flushes to disk and works more like the MEMORY storage engine but would still remain true to the features of InnoDB that we would expect in production?

Comment: It can't be used in memory but you might find this answer useful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11099/is-innodb-engine-up-to-speed-against-memory-engine

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make a table both innoDB and memory- both are different types of table engines, and can't be combined.

You can, however, use a temporary innoDB table. This means that the table will be written to disk, but will be per session, and will be wiped (both data and the table itself) whenever the session ends.

Comment: It's worth noting that [in 5.7 temporary InnoDB tables got *a lot* faster](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/https_blogs_oracle_com_mysqlinnodb).